# MKOverlay that Follows User Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit, core-location, mkoverlay

I understand how to obtain the user location and how to draw a polyline between two given points. How could I implement a polyline that follows the user as seen in jogging or driving apps. Is the only way to save user locations and then plot the line? All help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE ANSWER FOUND**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you for pointing to Breadcrumb example code.